# Refreshing ListActivity after updating SimpleAdapter data

Tags: android, listactivity, simpleadapter

i failed to update views of an ActivityList after updating SimpleAdapter object that holds data !
SimpleAdapter don't have notifyDataSetChanged() method, and invalidateViews() is not working when I retrieve the listview from my ListActicity !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually SimpleAdapter has `notifyDataSetChanged`, since it inherits from `BaseAdapter`

[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) the doc